# Rails map.connect route with trailing slash not passing :id to controller (Rails 2.3.5)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have a page that shows our member's profile.

Everything works fine if it is called like this

```
www.mysite.com/members/membername
```

but this fails to pass the last segment as params[:id] to the controller when accessed like with a trailing slash:

```
www.mysite.com/members/membername/
```

rake routes shows this:

```
/members/:id                        {:action=>"showmember", :controller=>"users"}
/members/:id                        {:action=>"showmember", :controller=>"users"}
```

This is what I tried in routes.rb:

```
map.connect 'members/:id/', :controller => "users", :action => "showmember", :requirements => {:id => /.*/}
map.connect 'members/:id', :controller => "users", :action => "showmember", :requirements => {:id => /.*/}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because of this:

```
:requirements => {:id => /.*/}
```

You're telling the `:id` to capture any character. You could prevent it from catching a `/` character by doing something like this:

```
:requirements => {:id => /[^\/]+/}
```

`[^\/]` = any character except `/` (the `\` is to escape)

`+` = at least one character

`*` can still be used in place of `+` like your example, which would capture 0+ chars instead.

You might want to add regex rules to say "only alphanumeric" or something like that as well. If you want to fiddle more with your regex string, try using http://rubular.com/